# How to correct the code such that the loop stops when there is a data match

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

We have new entries being pulled into a Google sheet daily using XML (Sheet 1). We are using the code below to pull these entries into a separate Google sheet for end users (Sheet 2). The end users can then edit the data. We are trying to compare the ID numbers in Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. Each time we run the code, ID numbers from Sheet 1 that do not have a match in Sheet 2 should be added to Sheet 2. If the ID number in Sheet 1 already exists in Sheet 2, that ID number should be skipped. It isn't skipping the matches. Instead it is adding everything to Sheet 2 every time we run the code and Sheet 2 now contains duplicates.

```
  for(var i = 1; i < slateDT.length; i ++) {
    var bannerid = slateDT[i][0];
    var match = "No Match";
    var j = 1;


    while(j < gradingDT.length && match == "No Match") {
      var matchID = gradingDT[j][1].trim();

      if(bannerid.trim() != matchID){ 
        j++;
      } else {
        match = "Match"; 
      }
    }

    if(match == "No Match"){ 
      additions.push(moveColumns(slateDT[i]));
    }
  }
    if(additions.length > 0) {
    gradingSS.getRange(gradingDT.length + 1, 2, additions.length, additions[0].length).setValues(additions);

     gradingDT = getDataValues(gradingSS.getName());
    var sortRng = gradingSS.getRange(2, 1, gradingDT.length, gradingDT[0].length);
    sortRng.sort(3);
  }

function moveColumns(studentRow) {
studentRow.splice(17, 3);

var v = checkDefined(studentRow.splice(20, 1));
  studentRow.splice(10, 0, v.join());

 v = checkDefined(studentRow.splice(18, 1));
  studentRow.splice(13, 0, v.join());

  v = checkDefined(studentRow.splice(20));
  studentRow.splice(14, 0, v.join());

  return studentRow;
}
```

Comment: Is it intentional that the id is in column 0 of SlateDT and column 1 of gradingDT?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm assuming that your weird moveColumns function does what you want and that the column numbers mismatch per my question above. Replace your for loop with this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < slateDT.length; i++) {
    var oldID = slateDT[i][0].trim();
    var matchID = 0;
    for (var j = 1; j < gradingDT.length; j++) {    
        var newID = gradingDT[j][1].trim();
        if (oldID == newID) {
            matchID = j;
            break; //ends the j loop when it meets the match
        } 
    } //for [j] loop
    if (matchID == 0) {
        additions.push(moveColumns(slateDT[i]));
        Logger.log("No match was found for " + i);
    } else {
        Logger.log("A match was found for " + i + " at " + j);
    }
} //for [i] loop
```

This is very similar to what you are trying to do with the while loop but without managing to never increment J under certain circumstances.

Once you are sure it is working comment out the two logger lines for performance.

Comment: The moveColumns function is useless. I can drop that. When I use the loop that you provided, it adds the header from Sheet 1 as a new row in Sheet 2. I made var i = 1. Now it actually pulls in the first row of data but it won't pull in the subsequent 400 plus rows of data on Sheet 1. Every time I run the function, it pulls in the information from Sheet 1 row 2 which means that it's still ignoring the ID match. Any advice? @J. G.

Comment: I removed the moveColumns function but that did not help. @J. G.

Comment: What does the logger function say? Does the output have a mix of found and not found?

Comment: No, it only says "No match was found for" + the row numbers. @J.G.